# Make mathquill field scroll always with the cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, mathquill

When the cursor is outside of viewport, in Mathquill the cursor stay hidden unless the user scroll. Normally like in normal calculator views the mathfield should auto-scroll with the cursor so the cursor is always shown to the user.

Behavior of Other Math editors :
https://i.imgur.com/1JbRv2F.gifv

Behavior of Mathquill : 
https://i.imgur.com/9E15uS2.gifv

I have tried to check if the cursor is outside viewport then I scroll automatically but the problem is the cursor lose the focus and become a null element and I can't scroll to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the following code :

First I added a function to detect if the cursor is outside viewport (source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15203639/3880171)

```
function isElementVisible(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
        vWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        vHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight,
        efp = function (x, y) {
            return document.elementFromPoint(x, y)
        };

    // Return false if it's not in the viewport
    if (rect.right < 0 || rect.bottom < 0
        || rect.left > vWidth || rect.top > vHeight)
        return false;

    // Return true if any of its four corners are visible
    return (
        el.contains(efp(rect.left, rect.top))
        || el.contains(efp(rect.right, rect.top))
        || el.contains(efp(rect.right, rect.bottom))
        || el.contains(efp(rect.left, rect.bottom))
    );
}
```

I added onKeyUp Event to mathview :

`<span id="expression" onkeyup="onEditorKeyPress()"></span>`

finally, the function that do the magic of scrolling is :

```
function scrollToCursor() {
    mathField.focus();
    var cursor = document.querySelector(".mq-cursor");
    if (cursor != null && !isElementVisible(cursor)) {
        document.querySelector(".mq-cursor").scrollIntoView();
    }
}

function onEditorKeyPress() {
    scrollToCursor();
}
```